# Ubuntu 17.04 become freezing when typing bangla in browser

Tags: 17.10, freeze

I setup Ubuntu 17.10, my device Dell Inspiron 15.
When i typing Bangla using Avro it become freeze for 40s to 2 minutes.
Before I used to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
This problem has not happened before...
what can I do?
Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use Kubuntu. You won't have this lagging problem under KDE.

Answer (score 0):

Avro still has not released any update for ubuntu 17.10, you can try Provat but it also has some performance issue with the latest ubuntu.